# Predual of a von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra. Can we view the predual $M_{*}$ of $M$ as a closed subspace of $M^*$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not really about von Neumann algebras, but rather about Banach spaces admitting a predual (which the class of von Neumann algebras satisfies).

The predual $M_*$ is a Banach space such that $(M_*)^* \cong M$. Thus we have
$$M_* \subseteq (M_*)^{**} \cong M^*$$

The inclusion $M_* \subseteq (M_*)^{**}$ via the canonical map $v \mapsto \operatorname{ev}_v$ is isometric and $M_*$ is a Banach space, so the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: If $M$ is a VNA, what does the predual $M_{*}$ look like? How to construct $M_{*}$?

Comment: One possible construction using trace class operators is described in chapter 4 of Murphy's book "$C^*$-algebras and operator theory".